# Count a character in a string split into 4's

Tags: php, for-loop

I have an output string/array for example of 001100110011. Every fourth character depicts a single unit. I would like to calculate the number of 1's in each unit.

So for the above I would like a return of 2,2,2. If the string was 0100001100111 then It should return 1,2,3.

My current script only counts at every fourth loop so 0100001100111 would return 1,3,6.

```
        $u = 16;//total of entries /4 is one unit


    for($i=0;$i<=$u;$i++){

    if(($i % 4) == 0){if($i==0){}else {$str .= substr_count($util_end, '1');}}

    $util_end .= $_POST['userinput'.$b];
// util_end is the input from user on a checkbox select 0 for unselected and 1 for selected in sets of four ex 0110 (two selected)


    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$input = "010101010001001";

$result = array_map(function($i){

    return substr_count($i, "1");

}, str_split($input, 4));
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/daixlB

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: I have some editing to do on my page but this works perfectly! Thanks @peter

Comment: you have pretty much made my day, I can now change a few more of my pages using this function I was blind to!